# add favourite icon to room db

Tags: java, android

i wanna to add item to favourite with room db when click the favourite icon i can't implement that with dao i searched a lot but i can't find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this [link](https://acomputerengineer.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/room-sqlite-demo-with-crud-operations-in-android/) implemented room with create, update, read, delete options

For a favorite item, you have 2 approaches

First way: create favorite_table and insert the item in the table, or delete

Second way: create a column in data_table such as is_favorite with a boolean value, when changing favorite state change value in the table with true or false